# Enzyme shallow options.context not working

Tags: enzyme

I'm studying the Enzyme docs, and this example isn't working:

https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/context.html

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

test('context', () => {
  class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
      return <div>{this.context.foo}</div>;
    }
  }

  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />, { context: { foo: 10 } });
  expect(wrapper.context().foo).toBe(10);
  expect(wrapper.context('foo')).toBe(10);
});
```

Result:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected)

Expected value to be (using ===):
  10
Received:
  undefined
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-enzyme-sandbox-8mxxb